# Speed difference between caret and klaR packages, for Naive Bayes

Tags: r, classification, r-caret, naivebayes, grid-search

I'm running a Naive Bayes model, and using the `klaR` package directly is very fast, less than a second to compute on a standard laptop:

`mod <- NaiveBayes(category ~ ., data=training, na.action = na.omit)`

However, using the `caret` packages's `train()` interface--which I thought was simply a wrapper for the above function--takes a very long time:

`mod <- train(category ~ ., data=training, na.action = na.omit,  method="nb")`

I'm guessing this is because `train` defaults to include some resampling. I tried including `trControl = trainControl(method = "none")` but received the following error:

`Error in train.default(x, y, weights = w, ...) : 
  Only one model should be specified in tuneGrid with no resampling`

Any ideas why this might occur or general thoughts on the speed difference between the two functions?

Also, is there any chance the speed difference is related to the formula interface? A few of my predictors are factors with over a hundred levels.

Comment: If you don't use the automatic tuning and selection of model parameters  you have to specify the model parameters (here `fl` and `usekernel`) using the `tuneGrid` argument of the `train()` function. See this [question](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/23763/is-there-a-way-to-disable-the-parameter-tuning-grid-feature-in-caret)

Comment: Bryan if you found an answer useful you can upvote it or accept it.

Answer (score 4):

Because when you call `caret::train` without specifying any of `trControl, tuneGrid, tuneLength`, **it defaults to doing a grid-search over all possible hyperparameters**!!

```
trControl = trainControl(), tuneGrid = NULL, tuneLength = 3
```

... and worse still, it does that grid-search **using the default parameters of that particular model** (NaiveBayes in this case)!

And the default for `trainControl` is absolutely not what you want: `method = "boot", number = 10 or 25`, which is 10/25 entire passes of bootstrap and also saving intermediate results (`returnData=T`).

So you override one bad default by doing `trControl = trainControl(method = "none")`, but that tickles that it's still doing a grid-search with `tuneGrid = NULL, tuneLength = 3`. You need to explicitly set/override those.

(as @Khl4v already said in comment)